# LFF in HP DL360p, how and is it a good idea?

Tags: storage, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I need a new server with 10 Tb storage and was looking at a DL360p with a D2600. It would do the trick, but it´s quite expensive and I´m looking for alernatives.

4 x 4 Tb would be enough, both for storage and speed I think. What do I need to buy to change it from SFF to LFF?

Is it possible to add two SFF in the back to run the OS on, two 146Gb 15K for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bad idea. A DL360p is not optimized for that disk layout. If you can spare the rack space, your path of least resistance is an [HP ProLiant ML350p Gen8](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/14226_na/14226_na.html), which can accommodate the number of 3.5" (LFF) disks you need and cleanly handle the RAID controller and SAS expander requirements.

http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/proliant-servers/product-detail.html?oid=5177961#!tab=specs

Comment: The entry models are sold with 3.5" disk, in what way are they different? It co-location, so 1U would be alot better...

Comment: The ML350p Gen8 can accommodate 18 x 3.5" disks. In co-location, you run out of power well before space, so that's the tradeoff. 5U for something that is cost-effective and well-integrated, or 1U (or 3U with a D2600) and more expense for something that will work, but requires more specialized configuration. There's more nuance to getting this to work with a D2600 and a newer server. I don't think 4 x 4TB disks is a good general solution.

Comment: How about a DL380p with 25 1Tb disks?

Comment: @Pontus You could, but I did not suggest it because it would be far more expensive than an ML350p with appropriately-sized LFF disks.